Windows 10 resizes and relocates open windows after sleep(monitor turned off)
I have Intel NUC with Windows 10 Pro and 4k monitor connected via HDMI. I have several opened browser windows with different size and location on my screen.

Case 1. When I need to leave my PC and go into hibernation, I do not experience any issues.
Case 2. I just leave it on. After certain time(power saving settings) Windows itself turn the monitor off. Whenever I wake up, the PC my opened windows are resized and relocated to the upper left corner.

When this happens, I can see in the Device manager as a hidden device default flat panel(640*480) which explains the phenomenon why opened windows were resized and relocated. Besides, I can see in the windows register
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration\GSM5B08343570_04_07E4_B6^FF90B3025EB9BD198400ECC60345284B\00
and Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Connectivity\GSM5B08343570_04_07E4_B6^FF90B3025EB9BD198400ECC60345284B
appears
additional entries 01, 02 etc. which have different resolution.
I have the latest updates and drivers.
I did try to use ASUS and MSFT support, absolutely useless waste of time and a bunch of nonsense suggestions.
Is there any other way except my CASE 1 to fix this Windows issue without any additional software?
I hope I described this issue clear enough, if not please ask I'll try to clarify.
I'm asking how to prevent Windows of changing the size and location of my opened windows whenever PC is going to sleep (turns off the monitor)
Thank you.
The problem: after wake up Windows, resizing and relocating open windows to fit lesser resolution.
My findings:

It does not happen if I force hibernation;
Whenever it happens, I can find the Default flat panel (640*480) as a hidden device in the Device Manager. Also, there are additional entries mentioned above in the Register;
It happens only whenever Windows turns off my monitor. I don't know how can I force Windows to hibernate, before turning my monitor off (as a workaround)


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I don't understand this request. I'm asking how to prevent Windows of changing the size and location of my opened windows whenever PC is going to sleep (turns off the monitor)

Please elaborate on the 640x480 - if it's hidden in Device Manager, it's inactive; however, I think your question is more to the symptom and not the problem, as the problem seems to be, unless I'm misinterpreting, the correct GPU/,monitor size isn't being detected, which results in the symptoms.

When the PC wakes up, all the windows are resized and relocated to the upper left corner. This does not happen when PC is hibernating.
Why is this happening? My guess that going to sleep Windows turn the monitor off, then can't recognize monitor (it needs some time to communicate over HDMI) and adds this default flat panel (640*480) as the monitor which causing the windows to resize and relocate. That is why I'm seeing this default monitor afterward in the Device Manger. Am I clear now?

Please notice, that there are no any issues whenever I'm forcing hibernation.  The issue manifests itself only when the PC goes into screen saver and THEN turns the monitor off and from my standpoint can't find the monitor and for some moment replaces it with the default, but later finds the correct one, but the screen is already resized and relocated. The hidden default monitor and additional keys in the register seems to prove my guess.

Could you clarify the 2 cases you present? In Case 1 are you manually sending the computer into hiberation mode? The phrasing of these two cases seems like you're doing the same thing: Leaving it, and so the different outcomes do not make sense. You can also go to the Power Management settings and change when the computer turns the display off. I would also suggest you delete the Display Adapter in Device Manager and choose the option to remove the drivers as you do, then reboot and make sure the correct drivers install, as this should reset any sort of "ghost" displays.

Case 1 I'm using Windows menu to force hibernation.
Case 2 I can use the same menu to sleep or just not using PC long enough that it goes to screen saver and then sleep by Windows. The result in both cases is the same: as soon as windows turns the monitor off I have this issue. I should probably try to turn off my monitor manually to confirm that the effect will be the same, but I really don't want to deal with the Register by clearing it.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/avoid-unexpected-app-rearrangement/
Pretty much the same issue, even through I have only one monitor
